# Is it possible to prevent creation of .directory files?

Tags: linux, opensuse

I'm on OpenSuse 12.3 and I wonder if there's a way to prevent creation of .directory files (preferably under some specific directory)

The question arose for the need of a "clean" directory. I'm compiling something and the source directory must be **completely original**, there shouldn't be any additional files. But the filesystem (or dolphin) creates it and the compile fails.

Is it possible to prevent it?

*PS. The compiler I'm using doesn't have an option to exclude specific files during operation so I just have to get rid of .directory files, at least in my working directory.*

Comment: What directory is created? When is it created?

Answer (score 8):

Dolphin uses those files to remember the view properties of each folder. You can easily get rid of them by choosing `common view properties for all folders` in Dolphin preference under `general` tab. But, obviously, there won't be specific properties for specific directories anymore.

Comment: I suppose making a sqlite db to store an (inode-id, settings)-tuple in some dolphin-directory would have been too much trouble...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have experienced, you can not prevent specific .directory-files from being created - unless you tweak some options for your entire KDE-profile. .directory-files store options specific to each folder. If you make dolphin use the same view-settings for all folders, you can prevent a lot of those files from being created in the first place. I also suggest turning off all sorts of previews for files within dolphin.

If the compiler can handle empty files, what about just creating an empty .directory-file and revoking write-privileges? 
`touch .directory; chmod 444 .directory`